# First derivative test in Spivak Calculus used without proof?

Tags: calculus

So I'm reading Spivak calculus and I noticed two things:

1. The first derivative test is stated and used without proof.
2. When discussing increasing functions, he presented the following:

[image]

So by using the mean value theorem, this says if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f'>0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$

However, according to my understanding the mean value theorem asserts a slightly stronger statement, that is $f'$ needs only to be $>0$ in $(a,b)$ that is, excluding the end points, and even in this case $f$ will be increasing on $[a,b]$

And this detail is needed when proving the first derivative test, for example as in [here](https://mathcenter.oxford.emory.edu/site/math111/firstDerivativeTest/). Am I correct?

**Edit**

So I'm basically asking what is the proof of the first derivative test, and the part that confuses me is proving the following:

If $f$ is (for instance) increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $b$
then it is increasing on $(a,b]$

Comment: His proof is fine, and your slight generalization (with the necessary continuity hypothesis of $f$ at $a$ and $b$ like in your link)  can be easily deduced from his statement.

Comment: @AnneBauval indeed I forget to mention the continuity hypothesis of $f$ at $a$ and $b$, thanks for noting that. However how does this generalization follow from his statement? Also this generalization is essential to prove the first derivative test, right?

Comment: Either directly in the proof of the first derivative test, or in the proof of your corollary, you can just say: if $f$ is (for instance)  increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $b$ then it is increasing on $(a,b].$

Comment: yes, how can we prove this intuitive statement?

Comment: Not "intuitive": For every $x\in(a,b),$ let $y\in(x,b).$ Then, $f(b)=\lim_{t\to b\atop y<t<b}f(t)\ge f(y)>f(x).$

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry but I couldn't understand your last statement, can you elaborate on it? Perhaps as answer for the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of:

> If $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $b$
> then it is increasing on $(a,b].$

Let $f$ be increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $b$, and let $a<x<y\le b.$ We shall prove that $f(x)<f(y).$ If $y<b,$ this holds by hypothesis. So, we may assume $y=b,$ and choose some $z\in(x,b).$ Then, since $\forall t\in(z,b),\;f(t)>f(z):$
$$f(b)=\lim_{t\to b\atop z<t<b}f(t)\ge f(z)$$
hence $f(b)>f(x),$
q.e.d.

Comment: why $f(t) \geq f(z)$, not $f(t) > f(z)$? Also is this a one sided limit version of half-the squeeze theorem? if so what is its proof?

Comment: 1) Although $f(t)\ge f(z)$ would be sufficient for the consequence about the limit, what I wrote is $f(t)>f(z)$ ($\forall t\in(z,b)$). 2) The consequence used here is simpler than "a one sided limit version of half-the squeeze theorem", whatever that means: it is the fact that whenever a quantity stays $\ge$ some constant $C,$ its limit (if it exists) is also $\ge C.$ It is a good exercise to prove it (directly from the epsilon-delta definition of the limit). Note that even wen the "quantity" stays $>C,$ the limit may be $=C.$

Comment: I meant $f(t) \geq f(z)$ after the limit, your last sentence in your comment clarify why, thanks a lot